# Unable to post to REST service

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, dotmailer

I am trying to post a list of 9 contacts to a website via api.dotmailer.com Rest service.

In my local test environment, this works fine. You can see the result of the Fiddler session of the local call.

[image]

There are 9 successful calls, one for each contact.

My problem is that when I publish my web application to our production server, the method doesn't even get used.

I think the call gets blocked somewhere before getting to api.dotmailer.com.

The picture below shows the Fiddler session of my call from the production server.

[image]

This is my question:

Under the "Host" column, the "Tunnel to" item shows two different results for the two calls.

From testing server: "Tunnel to api.dotmailer.com:443"

From production server: "Tunnel to myxxxxxx.com:443"

What does that mean? Why does the call from the production server doesn't get to api.dotmailer.com?

Comment: maybe there is some kind of a proxy server in the network topology. I would check the proxy settings on the production server

Comment: @Helikaon There is no proxy server set up on the production server.